# VBA: For each element in array loop

Tags: vba

What am I doing wrong, im trying to have each element in an array pass through a function but it not presenting the modified string...

```
Sub Trm(Trimmed)
    Trimmed = Trim(Left(Trimmed, Len(Trimmed) - 4))
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myarray As Variant
Dim cell As Variant

Cell1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).cell(1, 1).Range.Text
Cell2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).cell(1, 2).Range.Text

myarray = Array(Cell1, Cell2)

For Each cell In myarray
    Trm cell
Next

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).cell(2, 1).Range.Text = Cell1
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).cell(2, 2).Range.Text = Cell2

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey HukaBee and welcome to stackoverflow, you are trying to trim the cell with the sub `trm(trimmed)`, right? but in the foreach loop you don't call that sub. just just say `trm cell` to call a sub with an argument you should do it like this: `trm(cell)` also, why don't you just use the trim inside the foreach loop like this: `For Each cell In myarray
Trim(left(Cell, Len(Cell) - 4))
Next
`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing of

`Sub Trm(Trimmed)`

in

`Sub Trm(ByRef Trimmed As String)`

My code answers your question as it is. To make  you understand the difference between `ByVal` (default) and `ByRef`.

Otherwise, your problem can be solved in many other more efficient ways...